# Why do Both Tanjiro and his dad have the same scars?

Tags: demon-slayer

I realized when I watched *Demon Slayer* that both Tanjiro and his dad both have scars on their foreheads, and I don't know if this applied to his dad, but Tanjiro's scar is always changing shape and size.

Does Tanjiro's forehead scar have to do with anything about Tanjiro's dad being able to use the fire god style? If you have any info on Tanjiro's scar, I'd also like to know that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tanjiro told that, although the scar looked like a demon hunter mark, it hadn't been one until he mastered the mark, as [wiki](https://kimetsu-no-yaiba.fandom.com/wiki/Tanjiro_Kamado) summarizes it:

> He also has a scar on the top left of his forehead, which he received
>   when he protected his younger brother from a falling brazier. The scar
>   originally looked somewhat like a graze until his fight with the Hand
>   Demon during the Final Selection, after which it develops into his
>   Demon Slayer Mark.

Answer (score 0):

According to Wikia it's his demon slayer mark

> > He also has a scar on the top left of his forehead, which he received when he protected his younger brother from a falling brazier. The scar originally looked somewhat like a graze until his fight with the Hand Demon during the Final Selection, after which it develops into his Demon Slayer Mark.

His could have been injured in a similar way causing a scar that looks like Tanjiro's but as far as I can remember Tanjiro's dad wasn't a demon slayer but did use fire breathing. For Tanjiro the fire breathing doesn't so much have to do with his scar but, the scar changes because it became his demon slayer mark after he became a demon slayer.